# Have pointer function receive args from .get() closure?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use `facebookResponse` as a pointer function, rather than using a anon function, and have it access `req, res, next`? I thought about using `bind` but I don't know how I would bind the .`get()` method of the route. I didn't have success with `passport.authenticate('facebook',facebookResponse.call(this, req, res, next)`.

```
auth.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
  .get(function(req, res, next) { 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', facebookResponse);
});

function facebookResponse(err, userDoc, info) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  // I don't think !userDoc will ever happen because of mongo upsert
  if (!userDoc) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
  req.logIn(userDoc, function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    return res.redirect('http://localhost:9000/users');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a function to return a function:

```
auth.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
  .get(function(req, res, next) { 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', facebookResponse(req, res, next));
});

function facebookResponse(req, res, next) {
    return function(err, userDoc, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        // I don't think !userDoc will ever happen because of mongo upsert
        if (!userDoc) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
        req.logIn(userDoc, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect('http://localhost:9000/users');
        });        
    }
}
```

Here your inner function has access to the outer functions parameters (`req`, `res`, `next`) in a closure.

Comment: awesome idea! for some reason though, passport.js doesn't like it and it hangs at the route. There's no error so hard to tell why.